# Keeping only rows of a data table that appear in another data table r

Tags: r, database, data.table, subset

Consider the following data table.

```
dat=data.table(expand.grid(x1=0:6,x2=0:6))

 categoryvector=6
 points = seq(0,categoryvector,by=ceil(((categoryvector - 0)/(5 - 1))))
```

Which gives:

```
keepers = expand.grid(x1=points,x2=points)


   x1 x2
1   0  0
2   2  0
3   4  0
4   6  0
5   0  2
6   2  2
7   4  2
8   6  2
9   0  4
10  2  4
11  4  4
12  6  4
13  0  6
14  2  6
15  4  6
16  6  6
```

How do I keep only the subset of rows in `dat` which contain a row from keepers?

In the real data frame, dat, there are other columns but I only care to condition on these two.

Comment: Did you meant `dat[x1 %in% keepers$x1 & x2 %in% keepers$x2]`

Comment: @akrun should be fixed

Comment: Hey @akrun,  the problem is, I dont want to check uniquely, but jointly.  I think in this example its tantamount to the same thing, but not generally

Comment: It's just an inner join. `merge(dat, keepers, by = c("x1", "x2"))`

Comment: Suggested dupe: [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061)

Comment: Or just `dat[keepers, on = .(x1,x2)]`